# How to use older Checkstyle version with Maven build?

Tags: maven, maven-3, checkstyle

I am integrating a Maven project with an existing custom Checkstyle ruleset, compiled as a jar and available in a Nexus repository.  The ruleset has a dependency on Checkstyle 5.0, and is not compatible with newer versions.

I am having trouble configuring Maven to use this older Checkstyle version with my rules.

Here's my project layout:

```
root/
  pom.xml
  buildsupport/
    pom.xml
    src/main/resources/checkstyle
      mycompany-coding-rules.xml
    src/main/java/com.mycompany.checkstyletest/
      CheckstyleViolator.java
  [other projects with pom.xml and java source...]
```

And here's my parent `pom.xml`:

```
<project>
...
<build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
<plugins>
    ...
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0</version>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
                <artifactId>buildsupport</artifactId>
                <version>X.Y.Z</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>checkstyle</groupId>
                <artifactId>checkstyle</artifactId>
                <version>5.0</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.mycompany.checkstyle</groupId>
                <artifactId>mycompany-checkstyle</artifactId>
                <version>1.1</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
</build>

<reporting>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <configuration>
                <configLocation>checkstyle/mycompany-coding-rules.xml</configLocation>
                <packageNamesLocation>checkstyle_packages.xml</packageNamesLocation>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</reporting>
...
```

If I omit the `<version>2.5</version>` from the maven-checkstyle-plugin in `<reporting><plugins><plugin>...` and `<build><pluginManagement><plugins><plugin>`, and run `mvn site` in the root directory, I get a failure of the top level project:

```
...
[INFO] Generating "Checkstyle" report    --- maven-checkstyle-plugin:2.8
...
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:3.0:site (default-site) on project mytoplevel-project:
Error during page generation: Error rendering Maven report: Failed during checkstyle configuration:
cannot initialize module TreeWalker - TreeWalker is not allowed as a parent of com.mycompany.checkstyle.checks.coding.ImportOrderCheck -> [Help 1]
```

Adding `<version>2.5</version>` as in the XML above allows the top-level project to succeed, but the same error is seen in the first child project:

```
...
[INFO] Generating "Checkstyle" report    --- maven-checkstyle-plugin:2.5
...
[INFO] mytoplevel-project ................................ SUCCESS [4.528s]
[INFO] buildsupport ...................................... FAILURE [0.489s]
...
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:3.0:site (default-site) on project buildsupport:
Error during page generation: Error rendering Maven report: Failed during checkstyle configuration:
cannot initialize module TreeWalker - TreeWalker is not allowed as a parent of com.mycompany.checkstyle.checks.coding.ImportOrderCheck -> [Help 1]
```

I am certain this error is due to the latest version of Checkstyle being used, not 5.0, as I saw the same error when using the ruleset as an Eclipse plugin against Checkstyle 5.5 - it was fixed by rolling back the Checkstyle plugin version to 5.0.

What I don't understand is how the child projects are picking up the wrong Checkstyle version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer: the parent `pom.xml` needs these elements -

```
<project>
<build>
    <!-- http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-configuring-plugins.html -->
    <!-- doesn't seem to be necessary? -->
<!--
    <pluginManagement><plugins><plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${checkstyle.plugin.version}</version>
    </plugin></plugins></pluginManagement>
-->

<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0</version>
        <configuration>
            <reportPlugins>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <configLocation>checkstyle/mycompany-coding-rules.xml</configLocation>
                        <packageNamesLocation>checkstyle_packages.xml</packageNamesLocation>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </reportPlugins>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>

    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${checkstyle.plugin.version}</version>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
                <artifactId>buildsupport</artifactId>
                <version>X.Y.Z</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>checkstyle</groupId>
                <artifactId>checkstyle</artifactId>
                <version>5.0</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.mycompany.checkstyle</groupId>
                <artifactId>mycompany-checkstyle</artifactId>
                <version>1.1</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </plugin>
</build>

<!-- http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-checkstyle-plugin/examples/multi-module-config.html -->
    <!-- doesn't seem to be necessary? -->
<!--
<reporting>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${checkstyle.plugin.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <configLocation>checkstyle/mycompany-coding-rules.xml</configLocation>
                <packageNamesLocation>checkstyle_packages.xml</packageNamesLocation>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</reporting>
-->
```

The problem is, [TeamCity XML Reporting](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TW/XML+Test+Reporting) can't parse Checkstyle reports prior to Checkstyle 5.1, so none of this helps me!